# How to calculate matrix entropy?

Tags: matrix, entropy

I’m a French student that is taking a look at the matrix entropy ! Could you please explain me how do you manually calculate the entropy of a matrix ? My goal is to calculate it with a python programm.
Thanks for answer :)

Trying to calculate the entropy of a matrix

Comment: This is a very broad question. Have you started programming or designed a generic data flow? Do you have any experience in Python? Have you heard of NumPy?

Comment: Yes, I often create program on python and numpy is totally known. My problem is more on the mathematics side. I read a lot about calculating matrix entropy of 1&0 matrix but I don’t reach to calculate it by myself. 
Therefore, creating a python program is quite complicated :/. My goal is only to calculate the entropy of matrix full of 1 and 0, if you have an idea to do it I’m all ears !